# In git, when using difftool I get mergetool instead

Tags: git

I don't know how did I screw thing up, but now, when invoking difftool on git in windows i get prompted to launch the mergetool instead. This is my .gitconfig

```
[user]
    email = roger.planetgreen@gmail.com
    name = Roger Sepúlveda
[gui]
    recentrepo = C:/conseres/github/pruebas/jQuery
    encoding = utf-8
    fontui = -family Ubuntu -size 8 -weight normal -slant roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0
    fontdiff = -family \"Ubuntu Mono\" -size 9 -weight normal -slant roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0
[diff]
    textconv = fmbdifftool
    cachetextconv = false
[difftool "fmbdifftool"]
    keepBackup = false
    keepTemporaries = false
    cmd = \"FMBDifftool.exe\" \"/$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$BASE\"
[merge]
    tool = trimeld
[mergetool "trimeld"]
    cmd = \"/c/Archivos de programa/Meld/meld/meld.exe\" \"$PWD/$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$MERGED\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\"
```

FMBDifftool.exe is a c++ program to make binaries into text based, I already revised that it works and even changed it for \"/c/Archivos de programa/Meld/meld/meld.exe\" which is just meld. However, when I use

```
git difftool
```

I get prompted with

```
launch 'trimeld' [Y/n]:
```

Which should be

```
launch 'fmbdifftool' [Y/n]:
```

What's wrong with my configuation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[diff]
    textconv = fmbdifftool
    cachetextconv = false
```

That should say `tool = dmbdifftool`, not `textconv`.